# Unable to change nginx.conf file

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, vagrant

I have a vagrant-box running CentOS6.7 on which I am running docker containers. I intend to run flask applications served by nginx inside the container. I had to make certain changes inside the nginx.conf file to serve my application (app1) by nginx. This may seem a little strange, but I am not able to change nginx.conf file inside /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf

Here is what I did:

### Method1: Change in Dockerfile

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:flask
COPY ./app /app
COPY ./changes/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
COPY ./changes/nginx.conf /app/
```

./changes/nginx.conf looks like this:

```
server {
    location /app1/ {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /app/static;
    }
}
```

**Note the change in location in above server block from `location /` to `location /app1/`**

After the image is built and I run the docker container, I exec into the running container

```
sudo docker exec -ti CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
```

`cat /app/nginx.conf` shows presence of updated nginx.conf file (location changes from `/` to `/app1/`

BUT `cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf` still shows the old conf file (location is still `/`)
I thought maybe the second COPY line is not getting executed successfully and docker isn't throwing error on console (sudo?). So, I changed the conf file manually and did a docker commit -  the second approach mentioned below.

### Method2: Docker commit

After the docker container was up and running, I used exec to login into the container using

```
[vagrant@localhost]$ sudo docker exec -ti CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash

[root@CONTAINER_ID]# vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
```

Changing the file to reflect below:

```
server {
    location /app1/ {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /app/static;
    }
}
```

Saved the file `wq!` and exit the container.
After that I did `sudo docker commit CONTAINER_ID my_new_image`

Starting a new container and re-logging into container running on my_new_image still gives below nginx.conf file inside /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:

```
server {
    location / {
        try_files $uri @app;
    }
    location @app {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /app/static;
    }
}
```

I can tell that the my_new_image has some changes because it is larger in size than tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker because I had installed vim to edit the file. But somehow file changes are not persisting inside /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
Github repo: https://github.com/VimanyuAgg/flask-nginx.git

Comment: Update on this: I removed the COPY ./changes/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
and added RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf but after the container is created, nginx.conf is still there inside /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, the parent image has already added a specific file into the image, which is read-only. This means you sadly can't change or overwrite the file.

A hacky solution to this is to mount the `/etc/nginx/conf.d` folder into a directory on your host (let's say `/usr/local/share/nginxconf`) and change the file there, which is in another namespace and different permissions (afaik). It worked on my end.

```
docker create -v /usr/local/share/nginxconf:/etc/nginx/conf.d --name flask-test IMAGE_NAME

vim /usr/local/share/nginxconf/nginx.conf
```

Another, fancier solution would be to take another parent image, which doesn't add the file beforehand. But I don't know what dependencies you need for your app, so it might be a painful search. You could of course also create your own (which would also give you some training in writing Dockerfiles).

References to writing a successful Dockerfile:

[Dockerfile Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

[Dockerfile Best Practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)

[Handy tutorial to dockerize PostreSQL by Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/postgresql_service/)

Comment: Thanks for looking into the repo and finding out the read-only nature of the parent image. I have opened this as an issue with the author of the image. So, I will consider your solution as an answer. I hoped that after I do exec into the container with root privileges, I will be able to change the /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf file.. but as you said, I believe that the issue lies with the parent image. Thanks for all the help and for providing the resources!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to put your config file in a volume, so you can edit the file on the host and it will be changed inside the container as well.

To do that, you can run your container with

```
docker run -d -v /path/to/changes/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf IMAGE_NAME
```

After a change of the config, don't forget to test and apply the config with

```
docker exec -ti CONTAINER_NAME /bin/sh -c "nginx -t && nginx -s reload"
```

Also I advise you against installing vim inside the image, as images are supposed to be lightweight and unnecessary packages should abstain from being installed

Comment: Still didn't change the nginx.conf file. I totally agree with the advice of not installing vim inside the image. I added vim just to see that if any sort of change in image is visible. Providing the link to github. Request you to check and try it out.

Comment: I tried it out and got the same problem (changed `location /` to `location /api/` on the host, while the file is mounted in). It's a miracle to me why the file inside the container differs from the one on the host. It should be the same exact file. Anyway I assume it's got something to do with the parent image, as your app wasn't even started and the official nginx image doesn't have that problem. Do you depend on that particular image?

Comment: Actually I found the error in the parent image. It's entrypoint is starting a script, which sets the configuration to the wrong `location`. In your own Dockerfile you need an ENTRYPOINT to overwrite that. Dockerfile Reference might help you [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint). Also [Best Practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint).

Comment: Uhm forget about the comment before, sorry. A ENTRYPOINT won't resolve the issue. The problem is, that the file was created in an image layer beforehand (in the parent image), which is read-only. So you can't change or overwrite said file, sadly. I'll create a seperate answer with what you can do, gimme a sec

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I use the same image for deploy apps with django.
This image has a script that execute when the container is starting.

The solution for me works it was created a new file with my custom configuration nginx.conf then modify script prestart.sh add new line for copy and replace default file in /etc/conf.d/nginx.conf

```
create new custom file /mypath/file_Custom_nginx.conf
```

then add new line in script prestart.sh

```
cp /mypath/file_Custom_nginx.conf /etc/conf.d/nginx.conf
```

restart the container.

now for each reboot the script replace the file configuration nginx.

Note: I use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) for management services nginx

I hoppe it help you